# IOS 13 Combine Framework - @Published not working ("Unknown attribute 'Published'")

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I watched the WWDC 2019 session "Combine in Practice" (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/721/).

In the video they used the following syntax to create a publisher:

```swift
@Published var someName: String = ""
```

They did this so that `someName` becomes a publisher. However, Xcode doesn't like this syntax and gives me an error:

> Unknown attribute 'Published

I have no idea why. I'm using the Xcode 11 beta on macOS Catalina.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [Xcode 11 Beta Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_release_notes) (emphasis added):

> The Foundation integration for the Combine framework is unavailable. The following Foundation and Grand Central Dispatch integrations with Combine **are unavailable:** KeyValueObserving, NotificationCenter, RunLoop, OperationQueue, Timer, URLSession, DispatchQueue, JSONEncoder, JSONDecoder, PropertyListEncoder, PropertyListDecoder, and the **@Published property wrapper.** (51241500)

---

**Update:** This has been fixed with Xcode 11 beta 2. From the [Xcode 11 Beta 2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_2_release_notes):

> **Resolved Issues**
>
> The Foundation integration for the Combine framework is now available. The following Foundation and Grand Central Dispatch integrations with Combine are available: KeyValueObserving, NotificationCenter, RunLoop, OperationQueue, Timer, URLSession, DispatchQueue, JSONEncoder, JSONDecoder, PropertyListEncoder, PropertyListDecoder, and the @Published property wrapper. (51241500)

Comment: Okay, that's strange. In the session, they literally said that you could start right now with that. But thanks!

Comment: @silicon_valley: Thanks for letting us know!

Answer (score 1):

Available in Xcode 11 beta 2, but have to import Combine