# How to change thread using combine Publisher?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am using Combine and SwiftUI to do some async stuff, the point is that I don't know how to receive the response from the asynchronous operation in the main thread. The [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3204743-receive) says that it can be used the RunLoop.main, but currently in Swift 5.0 it isn't a Scheduler. So any ideas about this?

I have tried to use as per apple doc, but no luck.

```swift
anyPublisher
    .receiveOn(on: RunLoop.main)
```

Comment: Not sure if you’re having this issue also but when I do `receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` before `.subscribe(subscriber)` or `.sink(receiveValue: handler)`, they don’t receive the inputs. Have you encountered this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>`Combine` - at the time of writing - is not fully integrated in `Foundation`.</s>

According to Xcode 11 Beta [Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_release_notes/):

> The Foundation integration for the Combine framework is unavailable. The following Foundation and Grand Central Dispatch integrations with Combine are unavailable: KeyValueObserving, NotificationCenter, RunLoop, OperationQueue, Timer, URLSession, DispatchQueue, JSONEncoder, JSONDecoder, PropertyListEncoder, PropertyListDecoder, and the @Published property wrapper. (51241500)

---

As per the latest **Xcode 11 beta** (2), this has been fixed, so expect your code to work correctly.

> The Foundation integration for the Combine framework is now available. The following Foundation and Grand Central Dispatch integrations with Combine are available: KeyValueObserving, NotificationCenter, RunLoop, OperationQueue, Timer, URLSession, DispatchQueue, JSONEncoder, JSONDecoder, PropertyListEncoder, PropertyListDecoder, and the @Published property wrapper. (51241500)

Thanks to @Martin R and @silicon_valley for the [update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522258/ios-13-combine-framework-published-not-working-unknown-attribute-published/56522391?noredirect=1#comment99844367_56522391).

Comment: According to the Xcode 11 beta 2 release notes this issue has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks are due to @silicon_valley: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56522258/ios-13-combine-framework-published-not-working-unknown-attribute-published/56522391?noredirect=1#comment99844367_56522391 :)