# Not receiving inputs when using `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)`

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I’m trying to change to the main thread in the downstream with `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` but then I don’t receive inputs when using either `.subscribe(:)` or `.sink(receiveValue:)`. If I don’t change threads I do receive the proper inputs.

**Publisher**

```swift
extension URLSessionWebSocketTask {
  struct ReceivePublisher: Publisher {
    typealias Output = Message
    typealias Failure = Error

    let task: URLSessionWebSocketTask

    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S: Subscriber, Output == S.Input, Failure == S.Failure {
      task.receive { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let message): _ = subscriber.receive(message)
        case .failure(let error): subscriber.receive(completion: .failure(error))
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

extension URLSessionWebSocketTask {
  func receivePublisher() -> ReceivePublisher {
    ReceivePublisher(task: self)
  }
}
```

**Subscriber**

```swift
extension ViewModel: Subscriber {
  typealias Input = URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message
  typealias Failure = Error

  func receive(subscription: Subscription) {}

  func receive(_ input: URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message) -> Subscribers.Demand {
    // Handle input here.
    // When using `.receive(on:)` this method is not called when should be.
    return .unlimited
  }

  func receive(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Error>) {}
}
```

**Subscribe**

```swift
socketTask.receivePublisher()
      .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
      .subscribe(viewModel)
socketTask.resume()
```

Comment: Put some example code so that someone can help you.

Comment: try to be more descriptive of what you are trying to achieve and the issues you are facing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change thread using combine Publisher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56551108/how-to-change-thread-using-combine-publisher)

Comment: Thanks but the question isn't how to do it but rather why it's canceling the downstream when utilizing it. In other words, the answer to that question was now it's available in beta 2 to use whereas here I take that as a given.

Comment: Are you saving the cancellable? If you get back an `AnyCancellable` and don't save it then it is going to get deinitialized and the subscription will be canceled.

Comment: Yup now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AnyCancellable` returned by `subscribe<S>(_ subject: S) -> AnyCancellable` will call `cancel()` when it has been deinitialized. Therefore if you don't save it it will be deinitialized when the calling block goes out of scope.

Out of the videos and tutorials I have seen from WWDC, how to work with this was never addressed. What I've seen is that people are drifting towards RxSwift's `DisposeBag` solution.

**Update Beta 4:**
Combine now comes with a method on `AnyCancellable` called: `store(in:)` that does pretty much what my old solution does. You can just store the `AnyCancellable`s in a set of `AnyCancellable`:

```
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
    socketTask.receivePublisher()
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .subscribe(viewModel)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

This way the array (and all `AnyCancellable`s) will be deinitialized when the containing class is deinitialized.

**Outdated:**

If you want a solution for all `Cancellable`s that can be used in a way that flows better you could extend `Cancellable` as such:

```
extension Cancellable {

    func cancel(with cancellables: inout [AnyCancellable]) {
        if let cancellable = self as? AnyCancellable {
            cancellables.append(cancellable)
        } else {
            cancellables.append(AnyCancellable(self))
        }
    }

}
```